# Multivariable calculus find maximum and minimum.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I've been working on this for 2 hours and can't seem to work it out. Here is the problem:

Find the minimum and maximum values of the function

$f(x,y)=4\cdot x \cdot y^{2} - x^{2}$

And

$\{(x, y)  \in  R^2  | x^2 + y^2 <= 1, x >= 0 \}$

While it is pretty clear that the minimum is $f(1,0)$ I can't seem to work out how to find the maximum. I've looked at other examples but i just can't work it out.

Comment: do you know lagrangian multiplier techniques or kkt conditions?

Comment: Lagrangian multiplier is the one with the $\lambda$ calculations right?

Comment: Yes${}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Lagrange multiplier problem.
To do this problem, first take $\nabla f$
Then, take $\nabla g$, your constraint function, $(x^{2} + y^{2})$
The relationship between them is, 
\begin{equation}
\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g
\end{equation} 
For your case, your system of equations should look like:

\begin{array}
4y^{2} - 2x = \lambda 2x \\
8xy = \lambda 2y
\end{array}
Solve for lambda and equate the two lambdas together, to obtain
\begin{equation}
\frac{8xy}{2y} = \frac{4y^{2}-2x}{2x} 
\end{equation}
Simplify to get an explicit relationship between x and y, and then use that to replace either x or y in your constraint equation, $g$, and you get the value of x, or y, which you can use to plug back into your explicit relationship to obtain the other variable.

You now have some points, $(x,y)$. Plug them into your $f$, to obtain maximum/minimum values. Those maximum/minimum values occur at the corresponding points.

Another note: You may also want to test for $g = 0$ cases as well, since the constraint is an inequality. It would then follow zero is their *least* possible value.

Comment: I read up on Lagrangian multiplier as @user251257 suggested and solved it. But thank you for the answer! It is correct.